# Device Driver for java based Mobile OS

Tags: java, mobile, operating-system

First of all sorry if the question sounds too vague!

I am looking to write a device driver for the bluetooth for my mobile phone in Java.

Do I need assembly language or I can code it completely in Java. I am in the beginning of the process. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most lower level device drivers need to be coded in C or C++ depending on the operating system, there are some device drivers that can be written in a higher level language because they are abstracted behind a library and therefore don't need raw memory access or assembly. Two examples of this that come to my mind are USB and Bluetooth, so you are in luck.

A quick google led me to this: https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/

I would imagine that this is the library you need to write your device driver. I recommend that you read through the documentation and examples to get an idea of how it's done, and then start work on your own driver.